# Keep only n documents in collection - Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I want to keep only the latest n documents in my activityFeed collection, in order to speed up the application. I know that I could subscribe only to n activityFeed elements in my iron-router configs, but it is not necessary to keep all the entries.
How can I do this?
Do I need to check on every insert, or is there a better way to do this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can also use [MongoDB capped collection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you point out, your subscription could handle this on the client side, but if you also want to purge your DB there are two obvious solutions:

1. Use [Collection hooks](https://atmospherejs.com/matb33/collection-hooks) to delete the oldest item on every insert.
2. Use a cron job to find the nth oldest element every so often (15 minutes or whatever), and then delete everything older than that.  I'd use [synced-cron](https://atmospherejs.com/percolatestudio/synced-cron) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Better would be to create "capped collection": https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/

In meteor you can use it like this:

```
var coll = new Meteor.Collection("myCollection");
coll._createCappedCollection(numBytes, maxDocuments);
```

Where `maxDocuments` is maximal number of documents to store in collection and `numBytes` is the max size of collection. If one of these limits will be reached then automatically mongo will drop the oldest inserted documents from collection.

No need for additional scripts and cron jobs.